# Animation in appWidget

Tags: android, android-widget

i have made a widget which display images from sd card and then
navigate through it. Now i want to animate the image while i navigate
through it.I need to achieve following animation.

1step : default galleryView motion
  2step : perspective galleryView motion

hope to hear soon from some one. any link will be much helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewFlipper` and adding images to it. Check out the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply but you may now that we can use only RemoteView only so can you tell me how can i use RemteView with it ?

Comment: sorry no idea about RemoteView.

Comment: dear shaireen thanks for your your reply hope to hear sonn from some one